# plt.pause leading to improper subplot placement

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am following [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) tutorial, and I stumbled upon something I don't understand.

The idea is to have a function, that plots an image. This function is then called in a loop where subplots are defined:

#### minimal example

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np    

def show_image(image):
    """Show image"""
    plt.imshow(image)

def show_image_wait(image):
    """show image, and wait a little bit. similar implementation than in the tutorial"""
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.pause(0.001)
```

Now, calling both functions in a loop: 
no waiting:

```
for i in range(4):
    image = np.random.randint(0,3, (10,10))
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    show_image(image)

# expected output: 1 row, with 4 images side by side
# actual output: 1 row, with 4 images, side by side
```

with waiting, however:

```
for i in range(4):
    image = np.random.randint(0,3, (10,10))
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    show_image_wait(image)

# expected output: 1 row, with 4 images side by side
# actual output: 4 rows, with 1 images each
```

A function similar to show_image_wait is used in the tutorial linked above, where all images appear correctly positioned. 
I don't understand why waiting for a tiny bit overrides the subplot positioning in my case, and not in the linked example.

All of this happens in a jupyter notebook

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `def show_image_wait(image):`?

Comment: my bad. yes it should, but the issue remains. edited

Comment: issue persists with and without return statements in the functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see several rows is that for each loop run a new figure is produced. Independent figures are placed below each other in a jupyter output cell.
This in turn is caused by the one from the last loop iteration being drawn on screen and hence when `plt.subplot` is called another time, no active figure is present - therefore a new one is created.

The underlying cause of all of this is that `plt.pause(..)` does a bit more than only pausing. Instead it handles possible events on the figure and eventually *draws* and *shows*  the figure in interactive mode.

The [source of `plt.pause`](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#pause) is

```
manager = _pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_active()
if manager is not None:
    canvas = manager.canvas
    if canvas.figure.stale:
        canvas.draw_idle()
    show(block=False)                 #  <----  here the figure is shown.
    canvas.start_event_loop(interval)
else:
    time.sleep(interval)
```

where I marked the crucial line with a comment.

So in total, if you want a true pause as in "Do not do anything for x seconds", `plt.pause` is not well suited. In general it is also a bit questionable how useful it is in jupyter notebooks with `inline` backend, because that backend does not provide any interactivity.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work if you use `plt.show()` after the for loop but in JuPyTer notebook, the plotting is `inline`. A work around solution could be to use `time.sleep(0.001)`. You may try and see if it serves your purpose.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np    
import time

def show_image_wait(image):
    """show image, and wait a little bit. similar implementation than in the tutorial"""
    plt.imshow(image)
    time.sleep(0.001)

for i in range(4):
    image = np.random.randint(0,3, (10,10))
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    show_image_wait(image)
```

Comment: time.sleep indeed allows for proper subplot placement, but I am still confused as to why the original version gives these results

Comment: @warped: Could you perhaps try running your code without `%matplotlib inline` and using `plt.show()` after the for loop?

Comment: same result as before

Comment: @warped: Hmm. I think you should then wait until ImportanceOfBeingEarnest reads your question.